# how to save an image in python variable and then change it to grayscale?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, barcode, grayscale

I need to do  image processing for barcode. I know that I can save a picture and then load it in grayscale color_mode, but I dont want to load an image, instead I want to change the color of image into grayscale without saving or without having another image.

```
imag=Image.open('barcode.png')
w, h = imag.size
region = imag.crop((0, 20, w, h-150))
region.save("regions.png")  #I dont want to save this image 
img=image.load_img("regions.png",color_mode="grayscale")  #I want to do this work in a variable i.e. changing the color of image into grayscale without having a need of loading an image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using pillow.

In pillow, you can do [Image.convert()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert)

To convert to grayscale, do `Image.convert('LA')`

The mode `LA` is combination of "8-bit pixels, black and white" and "alpha channel". See [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) for more about different available modes.

---

Replace you code with the following:

```
imag = Image.open('barcode.png')
w, h = imag.size
region = imag.crop((0, 20, w, h-150))
img = region.convert('LA')
```

Comment: Hi, would you like to accept my answer? as it solved your question?

Comment: Yes, sure. I did .

Answer (score 0):

If you can use OpenCV, cv2.cvtColor works like below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img_filepath = "your_image.PNG"
img = cv2.imread(img_filepath)
grayed = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("grayed", grayed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```